# Connect to Google Cloud SQL on VPN

Tags: vpn, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm new to Google Cloud, and I am currently writing a script to connect to a PostgreSQL instance hosted in Cloud SQL.

My script is very simple: it should connect to the Postgre instance and create a few tables, just a database initialization. I know the script works, because I created a docker image of the script and executed a job on Cloud Run, it works flawlessly. But my script fails when I try to run it on my local machine.

I tried two ways to perform authentication:

1. Service account. I created a service account and gave it the proper Cloud SQL permissions, download the json, set the path on GOOGLE_APPLICATIONS_CREDENTIALS.
2. Authenticate on the `gcloud auth application-default login`. Created the credentials for my google cloud account into ~/.config/gcloud

In both cases the connection to the database is never established and the script times out after a few minutes. I thought that the authentication parameters or permissions were somehow incorrect, so I tested the same script with the authentication methods above on a remote server and the script works. Same code, same authentication works in the server, but not in my computer. So it is definitely an issue in my local computer.

A bit about my local connection. I'm a country with severe internet restrictions, thus, to be able to use Google Cloud (even Google), I have to route all my connections though a VPN. It is not a problem to use Google Cloud, I can access the platform and use gcloud commands, for example the command above `gcloud auth application-default login` works, but the issues appear when I have to make authenticated operations on google applications. What could it be? Doesn't Google Cloud authentication like this over VPN? is there an additional step to work with it via VPN?

Thank you so much for your help.

EDIT: short edit, I look it up online, but found no article with a similar problem. So I decided to post here.

Comment: Have you considered that you need to collect and provide the before/after routing tables and tests for the IP address and port that you are connecting to in order to pursue this?

Comment: Use the Google Cloud SQL Auth Proxy: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/sql-proxy

Answer (score 2):

Posting this as a community for the benefits of others.

---

As mentioned by @John Hanley:

> Use the Google Cloud SQL Auth Proxy: About the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy

---

The Cloud SQL Auth Proxy is a Cloud SQL connector that provides secure access to your instances without a need for Authorized networks or for configuring SSL.